# How to get rid of /tmp/.java_pid<number> files in Linux?

Tags: java, linux

I noticed a lot of file `/tmp/.java_pid<...>` in my Linux machine. The `file` command says they are sockets. Assuming they are created by Java I wonder why Java does not clean them up. How to make Java clean them up or just not create them?

Comment: I have never seen these files before, but I have only need developing in Java for 14 years. Google didn't find anything either.  Which JVM and version are you using?  What command line parameters are you using?

Comment: Sorry, the file name pattern I wrote was wrong. The files are /tmp/.java_pid<...>. The are probably from http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/tools/attach/LinuxVirtualMachine.java.html

Comment: Of course, you have never seen them since they are _hidden_ files ;)

Comment: If I run `ls -la /tmp` on my linux box when java processes are running I still don't see any. I can run `jps -lvm` and it can see the all the Java processes on my box. I am using Oracle Java 7.

Answer (score 7):

These files are created by the JVM to support debugging. It's part of the [`attach`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/tools/attach/LinuxVirtualMachine.java.html) api.

If you don't want java to create them then start java apps without debugging enabled.

You can safely delete them if there isn't a jvm with the corresponding pid... a task that is eminently suitable for a cron job.

A little bit of bash:

```
for file in /tmp/.java-[0-9]*; do
  [ -d /proc/${file#*.java-} ] || rm -f $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

pid files are generally the location where applications store their process id, so the user can kill the process easily afterwards. These applications should be deleting these files when they close down.

I wouldn't worry about these files too much, unless you are seeing more and more of them and they dont get deleted, then it might be a tell tale sign that you have an application that is not shutting down correctly,

Comment: These files have nothing to do with 'pid files' they're debugging sockets for attaching to the process for debugging